# Batch: Copy files which last modification were 15 minutes before

Tags: windows, batch-file, time

I have a folder where files are automatically created and I need every 5 minutes to copy the new files (that is, the files whose last modification was in the last 5 minutes).

```
 :loop
for %a in (C:\test\*) do (
 set FileDate=%~ta
)
 timeout /t 300
 goto loop
```

That's the way I have found to get date of file but I don't know how to compare and get the current date less 5 minutes.

(The copy command is not necessary, because is via SSH and this problem is resolved).

Comment: 5 or 15 minutes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In batch date time calculations are a very tedious task.

I suggest to use PowerShell (at least as a tool)

To get the files created in the current directory in the last 5 minutes.
This powershell command will output a `dir`-like listing:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'X:\path'|Where-Object {((Get-Date) - $_.LastWriteTime).TotalMinutes -le 5}
```

To restrict this to only the FullName you can append the pipe

```
| Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
```

or simply enclose the command in parentheses and append (...).FullName

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path 'X:\path'|Where-Object {((Get-Date) - $_.LastWriteTime).TotalMinutes -le 5}).FullName
```

---

Wrapped in a batch

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\11\08\SO_53206386.cmd
@Echo off
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in (`
  powershell -Nop -C "(Get-ChildItem -Path 'X:\path' -File |Where-Object {((Get-Date) - $_.LastWriteTime).TotalMinutes -le 15}).FullName"
`) Do Echo %%A
```

Sample output of this batch (listing itself)

```
> SO_53206386.cmd
Q:\Test\2018\11\08\SO_53206386.cmd
```

The `-File` parameter requires PowerShell v3+ but can be replaced with another piped command

```
| Where-Object {!($PSISContainer)}
```

filtering out folders. (The opposite is `-Directory` or no `!` for not)

```
@Echo off
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in (`
  powershell -Nop -C "(Get-ChildItem -Path 'X:\path' | Where-Object {!($PSISContainer)}| Where-Object {((Get-Date) - $_.LastWriteTime).TotalMinutes -le 15}).FullName"
`) Do Echo %%A
```

Comment: Thanks you. I am a bit lost...First of all, what I have to do to execute this command because in CMD I get error it is not recognized as an internal or external command,
program or batch file executable.

Comment: The 1st line has to be executed in powershell or saved as a `.ps1` file, the 2nd save as .bat/.cmd file and execute.

Comment: I'm still lost... I want to execute only 1 file (because I will have to execute this every day...) I have to install something? Where I can write the path?..

Comment: Modified the batch, change `X:\path` to fit your environment.

Comment: @Mofi did some edits to explain powershell behaviour depending on [PS versions](https://4sysops.com/wiki/differences-between-powershell-versions/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a completely different solution resulting in most likely the same behavior with the advantage that the last modification date of a file does not really matter. So if a file is copied into the observed folder, it is also processed even if its last modification time is not within the last **X** minutes. It uses the archive file attribute set by Windows automatically each time a file is created in a folder or the file is modified by a process.

```
@echo off
set "Folder=C:\test"
:loop
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir "%Folder%\*" /AA-D-H /B /ON 2^>nul') do (
    %SystemRoot%\System32\attrib.exe -a "%Folder%\%%I"
    echo Copy the file "%Folder%\%%I"
)
%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 300
goto loop
```

The command **FOR** executes the following command line in a separate command process started with `cmd.exe /C` in background.

```
dir "C:\test\*" /AA-D-H /B /ON 2>nul
```

The command **DIR** outputs

- in bare format only file name and file extension because of `/B`
- only non-hidden files with archive attribute set because of `/AA-D-H`
- ordered by file name because of `/ON` (not really needed)
- found in directory `C:\test` matching wildcard pattern `*`.

The error message output by **DIR** on not finding any directory entry matching these requirements is suppressed by redirecting it from handle **STDERR** to device **NUL**.

Read the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `dir` command line with using a separate command process started in background.

This output of **DIR** in separate command process is captured by **FOR** and processed line by line.

Empty lines are always skipped by **FOR** which do not occur here.

Lines (file names) starting with a semicolon are also skipped by default by **FOR**. This behavior is disabled by changing with `eol=|` the end of line character from default `;` to vertical bar which no file name can have anywhere.

**FOR** splits up by default the line in substrings (tokens) using space/tab as delimiters and assigns just first space/tab delimited string to specified loop variable `I`. This behavior is not wanted here as file names can contain one or more spaces. For that reason `delims=` is used to specify an empty list of delimiters which disables the line splitting behavior.

So assigned to loop variable `I` is the file name with file extension as output by **DIR** without path.

The command **ATTRIB** is used to remove the archive attribute from current file for next iteration of the **FOR** loop. Then the file can be copied to a different location or processed otherwise not modifying its content.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `attrib /?`
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `timeout /?`